# Paginating results from couchdb-lucene

Tags: lucene, pagination, couchdb

I can easily paginate results coming directly from couchdb (using startkey and limit) but looks like couchdb-lucene does not handle 'startkey' argument passed in a request. I still can use 'skip' but as far as I remember it's deprecated way of paginating with couch.

So, is there any other way of effective pagination with couchdb-lucene?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for couchdb-lucene's `skip` and `limit` query parameters.

Quoting the [couchdb-lucene documentation](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene#readme)

> `skip`: the number of results to skip
>
> `limit`: the maximum number of results to return

I realize that you're trying to avoid processing all of the skipped documents, but core Lucene doesn't offer any help to couchdb-lucene there:

To quote the [Apache Lucene documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#How_do_I_implement_paging.2C_i.e._showing_result_from_1-10.2C_11-20_etc.3F):

> **How do I implement paging, i.e. showing result from 1-10, 11-20 etc?**
>
> Just re-execute the search and ignore the hits you don't want to show. As people usually look only at the first results this approach is usually fast enough.